# Как сделать кнопку развернуть/свернуть без jQuery?

Tags: асинхронность, javascript, css, веб-программирование

Есть

```
<ul id="mytrips">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
</ul>
<div id="btn"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
----------

    window.onload=function (){
        var myTrips=document.getElementById("mytrips").getElementsByTagName("li");

          if(myTrips.length>4){
            for(var i=4; i<myTrips.length; i++){
              myTrips[i].setAttribute("id", "hide");
              document.getElementById("btn").textContent="Развернуть";
            }
          };
        };

        /* событие для кнопки */

        function hideList(){
        var myTrips=document.getElementById("mytrips").getElementsByTagName("li"),
            flag=0;
            if(flag==0){
            for(var i=4; i<myTrips.length; i++){
                myTrips[i].setAttribute("id", "dis");
                document.getElementById("btn").textContent="Свернуть";
              }
              flag=1;
            }else if(flag==1){
                for(var i=4; i<myTrips.length; i++){
                myTrips[i].setAttribute("id", "hide");
                document.getElementById("btn").textContent="Развернуть";
              }
            }
        };

        document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", hideList, false);

-------
```

Задача такая, что при загрузке документа скрываются li, если их больше 4-х, потом при нажатии на кнопку раскрывается весь список, а при повторном нажатии на кнопку опять скрывается все что больше 4-х.

Из всего этого не работает условие со скрытием списка при повторном нажатии на кнопке...
Помогите, плиз (только JS).

Comment: У вас flag при каждом вызове функции заново объявляется.

Comment: и,кстати, не обнуляется после сворачивания. Детские ошибки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    window.onload=function (){
        var myTrips=document.getElementById("mytrips").getElementsByTagName("li");
        flag=0;

        if(myTrips.length>4){
            for(var i=4; i<myTrips.length; i++){
                myTrips[i].setAttribute("id", "hide");
                document.getElementById("btn").textContent="Развернуть";
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", hideList, false);
    }
    /* событие для кнопки */

    function hideList(){
        var myTrips=document.getElementById("mytrips").getElementsByTagName("li");
        if(flag==0){
        for(var i=4; i<myTrips.length; i++){
            myTrips[i].setAttribute("id", "dis");
            document.getElementById("btn").textContent="Свернуть";
          }
          flag=1;
        }else if(flag==1){
            for(var i=4; i<myTrips.length; i++){
                myTrips[i].setAttribute("id", "hide");
                document.getElementById("btn").textContent="Развернуть";
            }
            flag=0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Огромное тебе спасибо... долго не мог понять, в чем проблема...
Если не трудно, можешь обосновать, почему мой вариант не работал?

Comment: почитай комментарии к твоему вопросу. И еще один момент - addEventListener лучше тоже вызывать в onload,а то может не сработать.

Comment: кстати, в FF не работает...(

Comment: у меня в FF 35.0.1 работает

Comment: тупанул, js отключил)